# why I cannot update wordpress on my local host?

Tags: wordpress, easyphp

I’m new to wordpress.
my wordpress version is on my local host and I need to translate the website to many langages. I want to use polylang but I’m not being able to because my version need updates and Im not being able to do on my local host ( the wordpress local is on my pc)

the message I'm getting is:
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17 v2\eds-www\wp-admin\includes\class-core-upgrader.php on line 399
The site is experiencing technical difficulties. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.

what can I do? any help

Answer (score 0):

You may receive a message such as “Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded” or “Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded”. This means that it is taking to longer for a process to complete and it is timing out.

```
  Edit file  wp-config.php:
Add the following to wp-config.php:

set_time_limit(300);
```